# Passing on costs to tenants

Tags: jelastic

If I am a Jelastic customer, does Jelastic offer ways measure and monitor usage in such a way that I can also split up the accrued costs among my customers? In other words, I would be extending the PaaS in certain ways to offer to my customers.

Scott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you deploy individual environments per customer you can simply refer to the [billing history](https://docs.jelastic.com/consumed-resources#billing) where you can filter by date / period and environment.

Comment: How many environments can I run? 
Can I connect multiple environments to the same database backend?

Comment: The number of environments is only limited during trial (number depends on the provider). An environment is just a collection of containers (nodes). Typically all nodes in 1 environment serve 1 application or 1 microservice, but it doesn't need to be that way: your application can use nodes from multiple environments. So yes you can have many environments connect to 1 database node. I suggest to put the database in its own environment for that.

Comment: One more question. Do you offer CDN access? Also, have you thought about partnering with OVH? They have some wicked prices.

Comment: We (Layershift) offer a CDN solution, but its purpose is primarily security focussed. If you want pure CDN we don't claim to own this space and there's nothing stopping you from using any preferred network according to budget and need. Re. OVH their service principles do not align with ours.

Comment: Yeah. After looking a bit closer, I noticed they seem to lack decent support. I guess they care more about cheap prices than good support and that makes me wary about using their service, even if they are super, super cheap.

The CDN bit is a bummer. It would be great to be able to connect an environment to a CDN, basically for the cost aggregation.

One last question and a tough one, who do you think are your closest competitors?

Comment: I think we departed some time ago from SO content and this should better be a discussion via email; but to answer your question: we strive to be, and I believe we are, the very best at what we do - the question is therefore mainly for each individual customer to decide if what we do aligns with what they're looking for, or if another provider meets their specific needs more closely.